# Symfony 2.8: how to drag the previous URL visited by the user for "back" purposes?

Tags: php, symfony, erp, symfony-2.8

I'm developing an almost complex ERP system in Symfony 2.8 and I'm doing a good job in engineering the whole system in order to avoid code replication and to adopt smart and re-usable code. What I'm struggling with is in finding a clever way to dispose of the previous URL visited by the user, to create smart "Back" buttons to place in my Views. Just to give you an example: let's consider the "single product" page. This page can be reached by the "Products list" page, as well as from 1000 of other pages (single offer page, warehouse page, etc). So, in the "Single Product" page I've a "Back" button, that must bring me back to the previous page, which is not always the "Products list" page! This is just an example to understand the scenario, but it's not the only one.

I was thinking to adopt this "Before/After Filter" offered by Symfony http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html#token-validation-example in order to store in a global variable the previous url visited by the user, but then I realised that for example in a single page I've also some Ajax requests to my Symfony, so I would end up storing probably the latest ajax request and not the url visited before the page I'm in now. And other problems.

I'm sure anyone who is developing mid-big size projects involving a lot of back and forth between routes had to face this issue, I would be curious to understand how this can be addressed in a smart way.

Thanks,
Guido

Comment: It's not an answer to the question you asked, but something else to consider. Your ERP app has a lot of interrelated parts, and paths to navigate. I wonder if a simple 'back' link is enough. Might breadcrumbs give the user more context as they look to retrace their steps?

Comment: Thanks Cameron! ya breadcrumbs would be a good idea! I was thinking to them but even more I would need a solution to track previous routes and paths that drove the user to the actual page!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this *jQuery* code (works for me):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.backbutton').click(function(){
        parent.history.back();
        return false;
    });
});
```

on some `link` or `button` in your HTML code. Or use similar solution.

Comment: Thanks, but let's suppose the page reloads itself because the iser is submitting the form for uodating the details of the Product. From that moment on the history.back() function would bring me back to the Product page again. I'' searching for something more advanced